# Neural network Learning Penalizing Rival

Tags: neural-network

I have a simple competitive neural network algorithm which I am trying to enhance by penalizing the 'rival', ie: The output neuron with the second-largest output. My code to do so is this:

```
 % Penalizing rival
        network_output(I) = [];
        [~, I] = max(network_output);
        delta = (1/current_run^3)*(sample'-connections(:,I));
        connections(:,I) = normc(connections(:,I) - delta);
```

Essentially, I removed the winner (neuron at index I) from the outputs, I then find the new winner (overall second), and I updated the connections by reducing the strength of those leading to such neuron using the standard rule. I also apply a decay in terms of current_run^3 where current_run is the iteratio numebr. I also normalize all weights before re-inserting them in the connection matrix.

However, by comparing the number of dead units to the network running without this refinement, I find that the latter performs better.

Any advice?

Comment: You mean that network without refinement works better then with refinements?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_learning
I just read that article and there it says 
3. The winner updates each of its weights, moving weight from the connections that gave it weaker signals to the connections that gave it stronger signals.
Also there I didn't find that you need to remove winner.
So, I not sure that you need to remove winner. Maybe that's why network with winner works better?
Sometime it is good idea to remove nodes from neural network during optimization, but after each removal network need too be retrained.